# What does "rigid steel" mean in electrical construction plans and specs

Tags: electrical-engineering

Reference to rigid steel is made in specs with reference to metal conduit. A commenter wanted to add 316 stainless steel as the material but this verbiage with regards to "rigid steel" still remains.

I have a suspicion that this may with regards to galvanized steel and therefore be a conflict, but could not find any information that would point to exactly what does the language "rigid steel" precisely refer to.

Comment: [LMGTFY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conduit#:~:text=Intermediate%20metal%20conduit%20(IMC)%20is,costly%20and%20lighter%20than%20GRC.)

Comment: I bet the commenter wasn't an electrician.  Rigid steel means thick-walled conduit.  I would talk to an electrical design house and actual electricians before changing conduit specs to something you potentially won't be able to thread or bend.

Answer (score 3):

It is to distinguish it from flexible metal conduit.

Comment: There's about ten types of nonflex that  aren't RMC.